# How to run a function over 'chunks' of rows

Tags: r

I have a function called textPrep. This takes a column of text and subdivides it according to the headers in the text as well as a load of other stuff. The function can't really handle more than 2000 rows before it slows and crashes silently.

At the moment I don't have time to redesign the function but I do need it. So I have 50,000 rows and I'm having to do something like:

```
output1<-EndoMineR::textPrep(MyText[1:1000,]$new,mydelimEndo)
output2<-EndoMineR::textPrep(MyText[1001:2000,]$new,mydelimEndo)
output3<-EndoMineR::textPrep(MyText[2001:3000,]$new,mydelimEndo)
output4<-EndoMineR::textPrep(MyText[3001:4000,]$new,mydelimEndo)

#etc.    

output1_2<-rbind(output1,output2)
output3_4<-rbind(output3,output4)
oot<-rbind(output1_2,output3_4)

#etc.
```

This is pretty awful and the number of rows is likely to change anyway. Is there a more elegant way to serially run a function over a number of rows so I don't overburden my function?

I did try parallel but it seems to be applied to lapply expressions whereas my function is not lapply based.

Comment: Write one function and call that instead by `m(M`apping it to output*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of splitting your data into groups, and then calling the function to each group (as defined by an index of length of your choice).

```
# generate data
n = 1e5 + 300
n
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(n), b = rnorm(n))

# define groups for function
breaks <- seq(0, nrow(df), by = 1000)
if(tail(breaks,1) < nrow(df)) breaks <- c(breaks,Inf)
group <- cut(x = seq(nrow(df)), breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)

# set up list for results of each group
res <- vector("list", length = length(levels(group)))

# fill in list by call to function on each group
for(i in seq(res)){
  mat <- which(match(as.character(group), levels(group)[i])==1)
  res[[i]] <- apply(df[mat,], 2, FUN = sum)
}

# results
res

# collapse if desired
res2 <- do.call("rbind", res)
res2
```

Comment: for fear of asking a stuid question, how do I run the parameterised function in FUN = sum ? At the moment I tried FUN = textPrep,inputText=mydelimEndo) where mydelimEndo is a vector of words and inputText is the name of the parameter defined by the function.

Comment: try `res[[i]] <- EndoMineR::textPrep(MyText[mat,]$new, mydelimEndo)`